# OpenAI Whisper: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, ffmpeg, openai-whisper

I'm not the first to get this error, however, all previous answers relate to ffmpeg not installed. As you can see, I installed ffmpeg so not sure why i still get this error. Moreover, this code works perfectly fine in Google Colab but not in Spyder.

```
pip install tiktoken

pip install -U openai-whisper

pip install ffmpeg

pip install setuptools-rust

import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("medium")

result = model.transcribe("F:/iim/dahl/01.Projects/20231215_Schlueter/02.Code/01.Data/The Investors Everybody Ignored ft Sallie Krawcheck  Whats Your Problem  Jacob Goldstein.mp3")
print(result["text"])



 Cell In[13], line 1
    result = model.transcribe("F:/iim/dahl/01.Projects/20231215_Schlueter/02.Code/01.Data/The Investors Everybody Ignored ft Sallie Krawcheck  Whats Your Problem  Jacob Goldstein.mp3/")

  File F:\iim\dahl\00.Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py:122 in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, model.dims.n_mels, padding=N_SAMPLES)

  File F:\iim\dahl\00.Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py:140 in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = load_audio(audio)

  File F:\iim\dahl\00.Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py:58 in load_audio
    out = run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True).stdout

  File F:\iim\dahl\00.Anaconda\Lib\subprocess.py:548 in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

  File F:\iim\dahl\00.Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py:109 in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File F:\iim\dahl\00.Anaconda\Lib\subprocess.py:1026 in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

  File F:\iim\dahl\00.Anaconda\Lib\subprocess.py:1538 in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```